# Strange behaviour of Scala for-comprehension and json4s

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-2.10, for-comprehension, json4s

The code below should:

- iterate over a sequence of strings
- parse each one as json,
- filter out fields whose names could not be used as an identifier in most languages
- lowercase the rmaining names
- serialize the result as a string

It behaves as expected on small tests,
but on an 8.6M item sequence of live data the output sequence is significantly longer
than the input sequence:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.apache.spark._

val txt = sc.textFile("s3n://...")
val patt="""^[a-zA-Z]\w*$""".r.findFirstIn _
val json = (for {
         line <- txt
         JObject(children) <- parse(line)
         children2 = (for {
           JField(name, value) <- children

           // filter fields with invalid names
           // patt(name) returns Option[String]
           _ <- patt(name)

         } yield JField(name.toLowerCase, value))
} yield compact(render(JObject(children2))))
```

I have checked that it actually increases the number of unique items,
so it is not just duplicating items.
Given my understanding of Scala comprehensions & json4s, I do not see how this is possible.
The large live data collection is a Spark RDD, while my tests were with an ordinary Scala Seq, but that should not make any difference.

**How can `json` have more elements than `txt` in the above code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not aware that

```
JObject(children) <- parse(line)
```

matches recursively inside the result of `parse`. So even though `parse` returns a single value, when there are nested objects, they will be returned as separate bindings for `children`.
The answer is to use

```
JObject(children) = parse(line)
```

the correct code is:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.apache.spark._

val txt = sc.textFile("s3n://...")
val patt="""^[a-zA-Z]\w*$""".r.findFirstIn _
val json = (for {
         line <- txt
         JObject(children) = parse(line) // CHANGED <- TO =
         children2 = (for {
           JField(name, value) <- children

           // filter fields with invalid names
           // patt(name) returns Option[String]
           _ <- patt(name)

         } yield JField(name.toLowerCase, value))
} yield compact(render(JObject(children2))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `parse(line)` is returning multiple JSON objects for a single line?

Comment: That was my first thought, but using `val txt = Seq("""{"a": 1, "B": 2, " ": 3}{"c": 4}""")` in the above code only parse the first record and  the return type of `parse` is `JValue`

Comment: Wait, `parse` returns a `JValue`? And you're then `flatMap`ing over that? Are you sure that's not iterating over every field of the json value or some such?

Comment: JValue implements `map` and `flatMap`. It behaves somewhat like `Option`, `JNone` acts like `None` and the other subclasses of `JValue` act as if they were wrapped in an invisible `Some`.

Comment: Thanks for making me double check. That is how I found the actual problem.